# Undefined Referernce Errors FFMPEG + QT + Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS

Tags: qt, ubuntu, linker, ffmpeg

i have 2 machines with Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS (64 mb) and the other is a snow leopard OS.
In my mac i work with ffmpeg without  any trouble but then i try to use ffmpeg in ubuntu and 6700 (!) errors appear:

```
error: undefined reference to `av_freep'
error: undefined reference to `av_strstart'
error: undefined reference to `av_freep'
...
```

I use QT 4.8.5 and g++ x86 64b
I installed ffmpeg following http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/UbuntuCompilationGuide without errors or warnings.

My test code is:

.h

```
QT += core gui 

INCLUDEPATH += \
    /usr/local/Include

LIBS += /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a
LIBS += /usr/local/lib/libavutil.a
LIBS += /usr/local/lib/libavformat.a
LIBS += /usr/local/lib/libswscale.a


SOURCES += main.cpp
```

.cpp:

```
extern "C"
{
#ifndef __STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS
#  define __STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS
#endif

#include "libavcodec/avcodec.h"
#include "libavformat/avformat.h"
}

#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    AVFormatContext *pFormatCtx;
    av_register_all();

    const char* fil = "/home/cits/Desktop/movFile.mov";

    if(avformat_open_input(&pFormatCtx, fil, NULL, NULL)!=0)
    {
        return -1; // Couldn't open file
    }

    if(avformat_find_stream_info(pFormatCtx, NULL)<0)
    {
        return -1; // Couldn't find stream information
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Any ideas??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your .pro file should read something like:

```
QT += core gui 

INCLUDEPATH += \
    /usr/local/Include

LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib/ -llibavcodec -llibavutil -llibavformat -llibswscale


SOURCES += main.cpp
```

Comment: If i do that i get:
    error: cannot find -llibavcodec
    error: cannot find -llibavutil
    error: cannot find -llibavformat etc

In /usr/local/lib i have libavcodec.a libavformat.a libdevice.a libavutil.a libavfilter.a libswscale.a and libswresample.a

Comment: Yeah i checked it. The ffmpeg compilllation put it in ther.

Comment: Generally the extension should be added automatically, but try calling it with ``-llibavcodec.a`` or ``-lavcodec`` or ``-lavcodec.a``

Comment: i wonder if av_freep is actually defined in these libs, maybe there is another avlib which has the required functions?